# IIS 8.5 Windows Server 2012 R2 error "HostingEnvironment caused shutdown" on postback asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms, umbraco, iis-8

I am getting an error in the Umbraco log every time I attempt to initiate a postback from a User control (.ascx file) button or any control with AutoPostBack enabled. I am developing in an Umbraco environment in WinForms mode, but I do not believe it is an Umbraco specific issue. The error is:

```
 2017-12-14 10:55:42,495 [P15164/D2/T3] INFO  Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase - Application shutdown. Details: HostingEnvironment

_shutDownMessage=HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown

_shutDownStack=   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
 2017-12-14 10:56:36,855 [P11668/D2/T1] INFO  Umbraco.Core.CoreBootManager - Umbraco 7.7.2 application starting on XXXX
```

The error indicates that IIS shut down or recycled the application or application pool, possibly because of a configuration change, but, there are none between one postback and another 3 seconds later.  I have researched this extensively, and it may (or may not) have to do with the Windows Server 2012 File Change Notification (FCN) feature. I have attempted to disable FCN through the app web.config, through the IIS web.config, and through the registry following a Microsoft suggestion. None of these attempts corrected the issue. I have also extended the App Pool’s error recycling threshold from 5 errors in 5 minutes to 100 errors in 5 minutes. I deleted and recreated the application pool for the site. It did nothing.

I am basically going insane. Does anyone have any idea what this error is and (hopefully) how to address it? Or at least point me in a general direction? I am continuing to research this in any case, but it is very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Microsoft [known issue](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-6338#) and Windows Server 2012 R2 is affected, have you installed the [hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3052480)?

I also see this error when working locally in Chrome when _shutDownMessage=Change in App_Offline.htm occurs, App_Offline.htm being in the root causes it.

I've also known it to happen with virus scanners.

I've had it happen on Azure which led me to [Shannon Deminick's](https://shazwazza.com/post/all-about-aspnet-file-change-notification-fcn/) page on this problem. I set FCN mode to single, we did some work on media caches and rebuilt the indexes, this sorted it for us.

It has also happened with memory leaks with UaaS, albeit in 7.5.3, there is a long thread on [our.umbraco.org](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/80488-recurring-application-shutdown-issue-on-umbraco-753) about it.

Hope that gives you some ideas.